# Media Type not acceptable exception when using SseEmitter

Tags: spring-boot

Following [this](https://www.jeejava.com/server-sent-events-spring-push-notifications/) tutorial, I am trying to set up a Sse Emitter. When I open the html page I get a

```
Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation]
```

On client side (javascript) it sais it cannot connect to the server. I have tried various other tutorials, but I am clueless on why my code isnt working.

I set up a clean test project containing only and exactly the tutorial code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Was in the middle of doing something else when I got the same issue.
The code below fixed it.

Simply put Mismatch Media type.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/api/push/notification",headers = "Accept=*/*", consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE, produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public String doNotify(@RequestParam("authToken") String token, @RequestParam("clientId") String clientId, HttpServletResponse response) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    response.addHeader("charset","UTF-8");
    final SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter(30000l);
        service.addEmitter(clientId,emitter);
        service.sendConnectedNotification(clientId);
        emitter.onCompletion(() -> service.removeEmitter(clientId));
        emitter.onTimeout(() -> service.removeEmitter(clientId));
    return "Connected OK";
}
```

any my event handler

```
 @Async
public void doNotify(String clientId, Object data) {
    SseEmitter emitter= emitters.get(clientId);
    if(emitter!=null) {
        try {
            emitter .send(SseEmitter.event() .reconnectTime(30000)
                .data(data,MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .id(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                .name("Notification")
                .comment("Client connection notification")
            );
        } catch (Exception e) {
            emitters.remove(clientId);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For anyone else that comes this way, it seem this answer does work but not for the reason given. Basically you have to send something down the pipe or the browser shuts it down with the 503. Once I added a throw away connection event this problem went away